# Access Totals dynamically updated based on textboxes

Tags: function, ms-access

All,

I run into some problems with totals using the DSUM function.

I have a Main form and a subform (details). The subform is displayed in datasheet view inside of the main form.

The subform contains a OppL_ID (PK, autonumber), Opp_ID (FK, is multiple times present), Product, Unit, Unit price.
Now I want to calculate the total revenue per Opp_ID on the main form. In the main form an Opp_ID selected, several rows with products are shown in the subform connected with that Opp_ID. If the user enters data in the datasheet view, the revenue must be calculated again directly.

I first try to get the formula working in the footer of the subform. But I cannot get the correct sum of revenue.
Now I have added in the query of the subform the Revenue: [Units]*[Unit Price]. This displays the revenue per unique line. I want the revenue per Opp_ID, so I tried the DSUM function.

What I tried:

1. To total the Revenue per Opp_ID I used the formula: DSUM([Units]*[Unit Price];"Qry_lines";"[Opp_ID]=" & [Opp_ID])
2. I also tried the control names instead: DSUM([txt_Units]*[txt_Unit Price];"Qry_lines";"[Opp_ID]=" & [Opp_ID])
3. I aslo tried to reference the Revenue field: DSUM([Revenue];"Qry_lines";"[Opp_ID]=" & [Opp_ID])

All of the formulas end in the result:

Example:

Opp_ID 51 consists of two lines with products A and B, Line of product A = Units 1 Unit price 20. Line of product B = Units 2 unit price 30.

Result: If I stand on A, the total revenue is 40 and on the line of product B 120.

I would expect only one figure:
1 * 20 + 2 * 30 = 80

It looks like it calculated revenue times the number of rows? What am I doing wrong?

I also tried to create a sum query and to reference this, for example:

Select Qry_lines.Opp_ID, Sum(Qry_lines.Revenue) as SumofRevenue FROM Qry_lines Group by Qry_lines.Opp_ID.

Now I get the correct figure per Opp_ID. Only I cannot reference this in my form? Perhaps with a Dlookup?

I think I am close but I cannot really nail it. Please help :)

Comment: You can do a DLookup on that SumOfRevenue query.

Comment: Ok, but what if the user edits the data in the form? Do I need to requery the query in the afterupdate or something?

Comment: Commit record to table and refresh form. Try: `If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False`

Comment: Ok thanks! 
I now have put a dlookup on the mainform.
I also added a save on the subform in the afterupdate event.
The formula on the mainform is dlookup("[SumofRevenue]";"Qry_lines_sum";"[Opp_ID] = " & [Opp_ID]
It looks like the figure only changes when I change a few fields.
When I add the formula in the subform, it updates immediately.  
I also tried to reference from the main form the textbox with the formula in the sub form. But this will not change the number too.
What can I do?

Comment: Did you try a Refresh or Requery command?

Comment: That was it, stupid I did not see it!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

Use DLookup() domain aggregate function expression in textbox to reference the aggregate query.

Commit record edits to table with code in control's AfterUpdate event. One way is `If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False`

In same event, use Refresh or Requery or Recalc command on main form.